# find corresponding values, when lookup criteria is identical

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a small table in Excel in which I am trying to find first and second largest in column `PTS` using formula `=LARGE(Q15:Q18,1)` and `=LARGE(Q15:Q18,2)`, all works fine. Now comes the part where I am getting into a problem, if 2 or more values are equal like `5` in my case, I need to find the corresponding value from column `F` to be able to check which is greater by looking at the second criteria. I have tried using `INDEX` `MATCH` combination formula to lookup the corresponding value but it always returns the matching value of the first large number in the column, which in my example is number 9 from the `F` column.

Question, how can I lookup the first and second largest from column `PST` and their corresponding values from column `F`?

```
F   A   GD      PTS
7   9   -2      2
8   8   0       4
9   9   0       5
10  8   2       5
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the following sample:

[image]

In the following Cells add the function:

```
D9  -> =LARGE(D1:D7;1)
D10 -> =COUNTIF(D1:D7;"="&D9)           And Autocomplete
F1  -> =IF(G1="";"";1)                  Only This
F2  -> =IF(G2="";"";MAX($F$1:$F1)+1)    And Autocomplete
G1  -> =IF($D$10>1;IF(D1=$D$9;ADDRESS(COLUMN(D1);ROW(D1));"");"")    And Autocomplete
G9  -> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(H1);$F$1:$G$7;2;);"")                    And Autocomplete
```

**I Explain:**
In D10 i found if there was more that 1 LARGE. YES ? -> in the cell G... I search If the Row are LARGE. YES ? in the column F I put the Index to compile G9 ...In G9 ... I copy the address (VLOOKUP)
After I can use a Indirect / Row function to use the data...
It's a little bit complicated, but work...
Oviusly HIDE the columns of intermediate Search...

Comment: This is a very complex solution using a lot of helper cells, it can all be done directly without any external helper cells or columns.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

The formulas use named ranges but they can hard coded too, note that they are array formulas so have to be entered with Control-Shift.